# Can I use a t-test for proportional data?

Tags: proportion

I have a data set comprising the diet composition of seabirds. For each individual sampled, I have the proportion of the diet that is comprised of sand lance. I have many zero values (sand lance is not found in the diet) and many 1 values (sand lance makes up the entire diet). I also have values in between (0,1). How can I compare whether the overall proportion of sand lance is different between years 1 and 2?

Can I simply use a t-test (with or without an arcsine transformation of the data)? Or does the distribution of my data require a more sophisticated modelling techniques?

Comment: What is it you want to learn from these data?

Comment: Why don't you know the name of the species?

Comment: @gung I want to know whether there is a difference between the years in the prevalence of sand lance in the diet

Comment: So all all the birds one species?  What "years"?  Is this a time-series? Are you comparing some years when something happened to years when it didn't?

Comment: @gung Yes, one species of bird. I only have two years of data, so I am just comparing the two years.

Comment: Do you think there is some meaningful reason why some are none, some are all, and some are partial? Does it look like there are gaps between 0 & partial, & between partial & all, such that they look like 3 distinct groups, or are the values continuous & equal density from 0 to 1?

Comment: @gung I'd say there is a bit of a gap between 0 & partial, which makes sense from a biological perspective. Sand lance is a preferred food item, so IF they can find it, they will get as much as they can. Are you thinking a logistic regression is more suitable, eg: absence/presence of sand lance?

Comment: Not exactly. I'm wondering if it makes sense from a biological perspective to imagine there are three groups: none, partial, & all. But 2 groups would be OK, if that were biologically meaningful instead (it just isn't what I had in mind when asking).

Comment: About how many observations? Can you show us a plot of the data, or better, post the data (or some subset, or a mackup resembling the data)?

Answer (score 1):

After some consultation, I decided to use a logistic regression.
I performed one regression using a binary response (presence or absence of sand lance in the diet), and another using success/failures (# sand lance in the diet vs. # of other fish in the diet). For this, I had to use a quasibinomial distribution due to over-dispersion.

Both models gave similar answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are specific tests for comparing proportions between two groups! Let us take a random sample of $m$ observations from group A and $n$ observations from group B.

Let $\hat{a}$ be the observed propotion for group A, $\hat{b}$ for group B and $\hat{c}$ the observed overall propotion. Under the assumption that the population proportions are equal:

$\frac{\hat{a}-\hat{b}} {\sqrt{\hat{c}(1-\hat{c}) (\frac{1}{m} + \frac{1}{n})}}$ follows a standard normal distribution.

For more detailed information and an example, check [Comparing Two Independent Population Proportions](https://courses.lumenlearning.com/introstats1/chapter/comparing-two-independent-population-proportions/)